# How to parse a string field missing quotes in a protobuf file?

Tags: python, parsing, protocol-buffers

I am trying to parse a protobuf file where one of the fields is a string that is not surrounded by quotation marks. As a result, the parser I use reads that field as an int. I would like to extract the actual string instead.

In the example below, how can I parse this field (type) into the string "CONVOLUTION" instead of 4?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import sys, os
>>> import argparse
>>> import caffe_quant_pb2 as cq
>>> from google.protobuf import text_format
>>> f = open('models/vgg/deploy.prototxt', 'r')
>>> net_txt = cq.NetParameter()
>>> text_format.Parse(f.read(), net_txt)
name: "VGG_ILSVRC_16_layers"
layers {
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1_1"
  name: "conv1_1"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
  }
}
>>> print net_txt.layers[0].name  # works as I expect
conv1_1
>>> print net_txt.layers[0].type  # reads CONVOLUTION as the 'int' 4
4
>>> print type(net_txt.layers[0].type)
<type 'int'>
>>> print str("CONVOLUTION" == net_txt.layers[0].type)
False
>>> print str(net_txt.layers[0].type)
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to read an enum there:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#enum

Converting to a string might not be the most elegant way to proceed.

I think that this should return True:

```
print str(cq.V1LayerParameter.LayerType.DESCRIPTOR.values_by_name["CONVOLUTION"].number == net_txt.layers[0].type)
```

Comment: Ah!! I hadn't realized that was an enum. Thank you, I can live with the solution you proposed.

Comment: I had to do some more digging to not use the field itself to extract the enum value, so sharing this here: >>> print cq.V1LayerParameter.LayerType.DESCRIPTOR.values_by_name["CONVOLUTION"].number
4